# How to create Siri shortcut for Animojis

Tags: ios, siri, automation, shortcuts-app

I want a Siri shortcut to open the Messages app showing the thread with myself. 
So I have to use the Open App action, and open Messages. But is it possible to pass variables to the action so that Messages is opening the correct thread? I tried passing my contact to the App, text with my name and telephone number, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to pass variables to an App opened by Siri.
Since there is no predefined action available that opens a specific thread in the Messages App, it is not possible to create a shortcut that fits your request.